# Unexpected result in dplyr summarize and group_by

Tags: r, dplyr

I was wondering why only changing the order of summary statistics (`mean` and `sd`) resulted in different outputs. The point that also mentioned in `summarize` documentation of `dplyr` R package.

```
mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  summarise(disp = mean(disp), sd = sd(disp))
```

`sd` returned as NA.

```
mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  summarise(sd = sd(disp), disp = mean(disp))
```

both `sd` and `mean` correctly returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first version the value of `disp` has changed with `mean(disp)` and it is this value we are taking `sd` on. Since we are doing this by group and we have only one number in the group as average it returns `NA` as it's standard deviation.

Let me break down the 1st example -

```
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>%
    group_by(cyl) %>%
    summarise(disp = mean(disp), sd = sd(disp))

#    cyl  disp    sd
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     4  105.    NA
#2     6  183.    NA
#3     8  353.    NA
```

Now the `mean` of `disp` for `cyl = 4` is 105.1364. This value is stored in `disp`. Now you are taking `sd` of the same value i.e

```
sd(105.1364)
#[1] NA
```

This get's expanded to all other groups as well.

A quick fix would be to change the variable name where you are storing the mean value.

```
mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  summarise(disp_mean = mean(disp), sd = sd(disp))

#    cyl disp_mean    sd
#  <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>
#1     4      105.  26.9
#2     6      183.  41.6
#3     8      353.  67.8
```

The second case, does not face this issue since the `sd` value is saved in variable `sd` and `disp` values remain unchanged.